# Java Script inheritance not working for google.maps.OverlayView

Tags: google-maps, gwt, javascript

EDIT:
After working on this for another day, I believe that I know what is going on, but I have not confirmed it yet. Once I know for sure, I will post it as an answer.

I'm pretty sure what is happening is that because the Google Maps API is being loaded from GWT via the AjaxLoader utility, the google.maps.OverlayView is not being resolved when the javascript library containing the USGSOverlay code is being loaded, so the line

```
USGSOverlay.ptototype=google.maps.OverlayView();
```

wipes out the prototype information for the object. I'm now working to dynamically load the USGSOverlay library after AjaxLoader.loadApi() method has completed.

An additional symptom: When the prototype is set to google.maps.OverlayView() it breaks both  the inheritance of USGSOverlay, and of a test object I appended to the bottom of the file. If I change the inheritance of my USGSOverlay object by adding these lines to the beginning of the JS library file,

```
function OverlayParent() {
}

OverlayParent.prototype.setMap= function(map) {}
```

and change my *USGSOverlay.prototype* to equal *new OverlayParent()* the inheritance works and I don't get the exception *this.SetMap(map) is not a function*.

If someone has a ready made solution to this, I would appreciate a link, but I am pursuing a solution similar to this [DOM-Based On-Demand Javascript](http://ajaxpatterns.org/On-Demand_Javascript#DOM-Based_On-Demand_Javascript)

---

I'm new to Java Script, but a very experienced programmer and this has me stumped. I have been working on this for a couple of days with very little progress. In the latest incarnation, I am copying nearly exactly the code from [Google Maps JavaScript API v3 CustomOverlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#CustomOverlays). The relevant documentation for OverlayView states *"You should inherit from this class by setting your overlay's prototype to new OverlayView.prototype."* I really don't think that the problem I am experiencing is specific to the Google Maps API though. Here is the code.

```
function USGSOverlay(bounds, image, map) {
  // Now initialize all properties.
  this.bounds_ = bounds;
  this.image_ = image;
  this.map_ = map;

  // We define a property to hold the image's
  // div. We'll actually create this div
  // upon receipt of the add() method so we'll
  // leave it null for now.
  this.div_ = null;

  // Explicitly call setMap() on this overlay

  this.setMap(map);
}

USGSOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
USGSOverlay.prototype.constructor=USGSOverlay;
```

Followed by the example implementations for onAdd, draw, and onRemove as described previously.

Stepping through the code everything looks OK, until the call to the inherited method setMap which throws the following exception:

```
Cannot load Google Maps API to your browser (TypeError): this.setMap is not a function;
```

Fire bug show that the **proto** variable is not set. So the inheritance is not taking place. I was originally calling the constructor via a GWT JSNI function, but to eliminate that part of the equation I wrote a second test Java Script object to verify that the parameters I am passing in are good. That function looks like this:

```
function TestUSGSOverlay(map,inBound) {
  var swBound = new google.maps.LatLng(39.5, -106.0);
  var neBound = new google.maps.LatLng(40.0, -105);
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(swBound, neBound);
  var sw = inBound.getSouthWest();
  var ne = inBound.getNorthEast();

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: sw,
      map: map,
      title:"South West Corner"
  });

  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: ne,
      map: map,
      title:"North East Corner"
  });

  // Photograph courtesy of the U.S. Geological Survey
  var srcImage = 'images/DenverWest.png';
  var usgsMap = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(srcImage,bounds);
  usgsMap.setMap(map);
  this.overlay = new USGSOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);
 }
```

If I comment out the last line the map display's correctly between the South West and North East markers with the U.S. Geological Survey map. My actual requirement is to display some text in a table div, but to mimic as closely as possible, I substituted the map scan.

I've read a number of posts on prototype inheritance, and I understand that it is a non trivial subject, but nothing I have tried has gotten any closer. I get the same behavior in IE 8 as I do in firefox. Any advice you can offer would be greatly appreciated, I am running out of ideas.

Comment: I think we need to see the rest of your code.  If I follow Google's example it works for me. If I modify it to display [this image](http://esp.cr.usgs.gov/research/central_colorado/denwest_map.jpg) and use your bounds, it seems to work and line up correctly.

Comment: [Google example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_overlay-simpleA.html) - [your example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_overlay-simpleB.html)

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed seeing your comment earlier, or I would have responded sooner. It's impossible to give you the rest of the code, as it is proprietary to my client. I will work on duplicating the issue with out their code, and try to post that. In the mean time I will bring you up to date with my current investigation. If I add the following :

Comment: `code`
function OverlayParent() {
}

OverlayParent.prototype.setMap= function(map) {}
 `code`

Followed by setting the USGSOverlay.prototype to a new OverlayParent The the inheritance works, and I don't get an exception. I think the problem is that the map API is not loaded when my js is, so the line that sets USGSOverlay.prototype to new google.maps.Overlayview() fails, and __proto__ is never set.

Comment: Code is very difficult to read in the comments.  It would be preferable if you added it to your question.

Comment: I missed the important part for the code.  The API not being loaded would make sense, but you haven't provided the code that loads the API in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I have not used Stack Overflow that much before. I will edit the question. So that it is more concise given what I now know and suspect.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to diagnose this issue and correct it. The problem is similar to a race condition, but I hesitate to call it that since the correct order will never occur.

The problem is that in the application I am working on, Google Maps API is loaded via the Google API's [AjaxLoader](http://gwt-google-apis.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/ajaxloader/1.1/index.html) object, and my USGSOverlay javascript library was being loaded as a part of the page load process. AjaxLoader loads the Google Maps API asynchronously from the GWT entry point method or in HTML world, onLoad, which occurs after the javascript has already been loaded. There was no error being reported, and the javascript constructor for USGSOverlay existed, but it the inheritance of the object was not correct. (As an Aside, can anyone recommend tools which would detect this situation?)

The invalid inheritance state could be seen in the firebug debugger because the USGSOverlay object did not have a `__proto__` member variable. To correct the problem I added logic to dynamically load the USGSOverlay javascript library to the onLoad call back method which is passed into AjaxLoader's [loadApi](http://gwt-google-apis.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/ajaxloader/1.1/index.html) method. Then the only remaining problem was this approach relies on the DOM to detect the additions to the page's head, and execute the script load. This in turn caused a real race condition where frequently the library was not loaded when the program attempted to access it.

Here is a link to an article that describes how I dynamically loaded the java script. [DOM Based on Demand Javascript](http://ajaxpatterns.org/On-Demand_Javascript#DOM-Based_On-Demand_Javascript)

To get around the race condition of the library not being loaded I simply added a

```
if (typeof USGSOverlay != 'undefined') { ... }
```

test before calling the `new USGSOverlay(...` method. Since my actual OverlayView derived object is related to a hover this simple prophylactic exception protection was sufficient for my purposes. A more sophisticated method will be needed if your Overlay is part of your initial display, but that's your problem :). There are a number of discussions on how to to that.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem but I didn't like the idea of resorting to dynamically loading the custom overlay script the way you described in your answer.

How are you calling the `initialize()` function?

I was loading the Google Maps API like this:

```
<!-- I omitted sensor=false so this would fit without scrollbars -->
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initialize">
</script>
```

**Notice the** `callback=initialize`.  This is what was causing the race condition.  I removed `callback=initialize` from the query string that gets the API and added this to the bottom of my **init.js** script:

```
window.onload = initialize();
```

That solved it for me.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

So according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes) the google Charts was released on February 23, 2016 and is the official current release.

And [This is what I found that needed to be updated](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#updateloader).

I Hope this helps!

Cheers,
Jay